# The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes error

Tags: error-handling, byte, sharepoint-online

I'm doing migrate data from sharepoint list to another list. It gives following error

- ```
   $exception  {"The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes."}   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException
  ```

is there any way to overcome this. doing this using C# code.

Comment: If possible, would you mind providing any code snippets you are using? In this way we can do better troubleshooting. You can also check whether there are any attachments in the list that are causing the file volume to be too large